# What is the correct way of configing Eloquent globally?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent has some assumptions regarding db tables.

- It uses plural name of class for tables name. I use singular nouns for tables' name.
- By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. I use `cData` and `uDate`
- I use camelCase to name columns not underline_separated names.

I know it possible to use class properties to overwrite those. What is the correct way to config it globally?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the `Model` class create a new class for example `MyModel` and setup your attributes there. Then extend `MyModel`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create your own base model that extends Eloquent. Then you can define new values for the timestamp columns and override the `getTable()` method:

```
class BaseModel extends Model {

    const CREATED_AT = 'cData';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'uData';

    /**
     * Get the table associated with the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        if (isset($this->table)) return $this->table;

        return str_replace('\\', '', snake_case(class_basename($this)));
    }
}
```

Then, let all your models extend that base model:

```
class User extends BaseModel
```

Comment: Thanks, What about column names? I use camelCase to name columns not underline_separated names.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything special about that. You can add `public static $snakeAttributes = true;` but that's only used for relation names and the mutator cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by editing vendor\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php file.

```
/**
 * The name of the "created at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const CREATED_AT = 'cDate';

/**
 * The name of the "updated at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const UPDATED_AT = 'uDate';

/**
 * The name of the "deleted at" column.
 *
 * @var string
 */
const DELETED_AT = 'dDate';
```

But honestly speaking, editing the core source is not a good idea. So you can do this by

```
class MyModel extends Model {

     /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'cData';
      /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'uData';

     /**
     * The name of the "deleted at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     const DELETED_AT = 'dDate';
}
```

Now write you model extending `MyModel` instead of original `Model`.
for example:

```
class User extends MyModel{
    //Yes, if you want to change default table name then you should do this. Shouldn't be global. 
    protected $table = "user";
}
```